# Pull Request Code Coverage Fails with azure dev ops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, azure-pipelines-tasks

We have the branch policy Status Check set to “On” and assigned the Pull Request pipeline.

This is for blocking the merge if the code is not meet the percentage of code coverage

Also we have some files excluded from code coverage which is added into runsettings.

But when we do some changes to the excluded files the pull requests status check is failing.

Looks like the excluded files are exclued from the code coverage report but included in the status check.

Is there any workaround for this?